# Erro de AudioSource com Unity prefabs

Tags: c#, jogos, unity-5

Fiz uns prefab e coloquei alguns deles em cena, enquanto executava um script.

O script é responsável por destruir o inimigo quando um jogador pisa em um colisor em sua cabeça (esse colisor é filho do inimigo).

Aqui está o script do inimigo (Frog):

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class Frog : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private Rigidbody2D rig;
     public Animator anim;
 
     public float speed;
 
     public Transform upside; // Parte superior de colisão contra objetos. (Só comentei para vocês não se confundirem, pode ignorar isso.)
     public Transform underside; // Parte inferior de colisão contra objetos. (Só comentei para vocês não se confundirem, pode ignorar isso.)
 
     private bool colliding;
 
     public LayerMask layer;
 
     public AudioSource audioSource;
 
     public static Frog frog;
 
     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
         anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
 
         frog = this;
     }
 
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         rig.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rig.velocity.y);
 
         colliding = Physics2D.Linecast(upside.position, underside.position, layer); // Cria uma linha invisível na frente do inimigo para fazer um colisor. (Só comentei para vocês não se confundirem, pode ignorar isso.)
 
         if(colliding) // Se colidiu com algo... (Só comentei para vocês não se confundirem, pode ignorar isso.)
         {
             transform.localScale = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x * -1f, transform.localScale.y); // ...inverte o inimigo; e, (Só comentei para vocês não se confundirem, pode ignorar isso.)
             speed = -speed; // inverte a velocidade. (Só comentei para vocês não se confundirem, pode ignorar isso.)
         }
     }
 
     void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
     {
         if(coll.gameObject.tag == "Player" && !FrogCollision.frogColl.isFrogDead)
         {
             audioSource.clip = Player.instance.deathClip;
             audioSource.Play();
 
             GameController.instance.ShowGameOver();
             Destroy(coll.gameObject);
         }
     }
 }
```

E este é o script do colisor filho (FrogCollision):

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class FrogCollision : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public AudioClip frogDeath;
     public bool isFrogDead;
 
     public static FrogCollision frogColl;
 
     void Start()
     {
         frogColl = this;
     }
 
     void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
     {
         if(coll.gameObject.tag == "Player")
         {
             Frog.frog.audioSource.clip = frogDeath;
             Frog.frog.audioSource.Play();
 
             coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * 10, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
             Frog.frog.speed = 0;
 
             Frog.frog.anim.SetTrigger("isDead");
             Destroy(Frog.frog.gameObject, 0.3f);
 
             isFrogDead = true;
         }
     }
 }
```

O problema é quando eu piso em um inimigo com vários inimigos na mesma cena. O inimigo pisoteado não é destruído, mas sim outro.

Então, eu continuo pisando no inimigo e dá este erro no console:

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'AudioSource' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
> Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
> FrogCollision.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D coll) (at Assets/Scripts/FrogCollision.cs:21)

Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Acontece que voce não está destruindo o objeto no qual está colidindo, seria mais prático voce criar uma tag "Enemy" e colocar nos Frogs e depois ja colocar um script de colisão do player com o inimigo, mas voce faz o contrário e acaba destruindo o outro objeto quando colide. Tente deixar seu script FrogCollision assim:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class FrogCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip frogDeath;
    public bool isFrogDead;
 
    public static FrogCollision frogColl;
 
    void Start()
    {
        frogColl = this;
    }
 
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        if(coll.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            AudioSource frogAud = this.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            frogAud.clip = frogDea
            frogAud.Play();
 
            coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * 10, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            Frog.frog.speed = 0;

            Frog.frog.anim.SetTrigger("isDead");
            Destroy(this.transform.parent.gameObject, 0.3f);
 
            isFrogDead = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu peguei este script que você me mandou. Funciona, mas ainda assim tem bugs. Então eu fui fazer a sugestão que disse, coloquei uma tag no objeto filho e fiz a verificação no script do player. Testando, vi que a colisão não estava sendo feita de jeito nenhum. Me certifiquei de que o colisor e o player estava colidindo, mas mesmo assim não aparecia nenhum log que coloquei no script.

Comment: Que tipo de bugs?

Comment: Foi mal não dar detalhes, mas explicando...

O sapo que piso, de fato, se destrói, mas não executa a animação de morte. Outro sapo da cena é que executa tal animação; e também, para de andar.

Comment: Se eu mudar a linha `Frog.frog.anim.SetTrigger("isDead");` para `this.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("isDead");`, o sapo não executa a animação, mas ainda assim fica parado. Tem alguma maneira de acessar uma variável pública usando o `this.transform.parent.gameObject`?

Comment: Eu consegui resolver!!! Para eu pegar uma variável do componente pai, eu tenho que usar isso: `this.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<[nome do script, no meu caso, Frog]>()`. Dessa maneira consegui fazer com que todos sejam destruídos sem atrapalhar outro inimigo. Obrigado pela ajuda, Poke Clash!!! 

Comment: Denada :). Boa Sorte!